# How to have a unique ID number in CRM Online 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using CRM Online 2013 and in my custom entity there is a unique field by the name of `ID`. This ID is manually entered and needs to be unique. Is there a way to check whether the ID has been entered before in some other record? For example if there are previous records with ID's 111, 222, 333 and if a user tries to save a new record with ID=111 it should give an alert.

Comment: Why you want user to enter the unique number? It is frustrating for users.

Comment: Have a look at the answer by salyh here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468503/using-sql-server-application-locks-to-solve-locking-requirements for a well explained method of doing auto numbering using CRM plugins

Comment: Sadly guys entering the ID manually is a requirement, otherwise I am aware of auto-numbering plugins.

Comment: Ok, in that case you are going to be limited to Scorpions answer, or alternatively you could do a client side check using javascript to do the same sort of query with an alert message. You are going to have trouble making it 100% reliable in any case though if there is the possibility of multiple records getting created close together. It *may* have been possible with the duplicate detection functionality in CRM 2011, but I believe it has changed enough in 2013 to make it unsuitable for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a two prong approach.  Perform an Odata via javascript during the onChange event of the Id Field, and warn the user if it's already in use.  This could be all that would be required, but it leaves open the possibility of a race condition between Person A and Person B entering the same id in at the same time.  In this case you'll need a plugin to confirm that it is unique.

The Odata call makes it much easier on the user since they get immediate feed back, the Plugin just helps to close the race condition Gap.

Comment: Hi @Daryl, I understand that Odata via JavaScript can provide immediate feedback and user don't need to press the save button to get the error message. But I think its bit of overkill to have Odata call and plugin both checking the same thing on a process. I understand it can eliminate the trial and error thing for user (no need to press same to try), but still we are running an extra query.

Comment: @Scorpion Agreed. It's all about user experience and if it's worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

However, I am not in favour of user typed unique number. For performance reasons, it should be Auto generated. Moreover, it can be frustrating for user if they had to key in a number many times to find a unique number. Its impossible for user to guess the unique number unless you have any defined pattern.

But still you can achieve what you want by writing a plugin on pre-validation or pre-operation. In plugin check for the existing records where Id is equal to given Id. If it is previously used, thrown new `InvalidPluginExecutionException` with error message.

As it is going to be a heavy query if you have millions of records in Database, I would recommend you to have SQL index on this column to improve the processing time. Or Per populate the field with unique auto generated.

Comment: The OP mentions CRM Online so will be unable to apply custom indexes. Also your solution does not account for concurrency issues that will occur (edit: didn't see your last sentence originally). There are *ok* methods for auto numbering in CRM available that utilise plugins and database transactions to ensure uniqueness

Comment: A unique ID field sounds like exactly the kind of field I would add to the Find Columns in the Quick Find View to make sure that users can search on this field. Adding the field to Quick Find columns will automatically add a nonclustered index for this column, in 2013 (including Online).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough and untested example of the basic code you need to use to check for uniqueness of a value. I recommend putting an index on the unique field and the primary key field to improve performance if you expect a high record count or lots record creation.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Determines if the uniqueField contains a unique value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityName">Logical Name of the entity being checked</param>
    /// <param name="uniqueField">Field on the entity to check for uniqueness</param>
    /// <param name="recordIdField">Field on the entity that is hte Primary Key (not attribute) of the Entity - should be logical name of the entity followed by 'id' (i.e., accountid)</param>
    /// <param name="valueToCheck">Value to ensure is unique to this record</param>
    /// <param name="currentRecordId">Id (Primary Key) of the current record</param>
    /// <param name="service">An instance of IOrganizationService with Organization-wide permission to read the entity</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool isUniqueRecord(string entityName, string uniqueField, string recordIdField, string valueToCheck, Guid currentRecordId, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var query = new QueryExpression(entityName)
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
        };

        var criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(uniqueField, ConditionOperator.Equal, valueToCheck));
        criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(recordIdField, ConditionOperator.NotEqual, currentRecordId));

        query.Criteria = criteria;

        var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        if (result.Entities.Any()) return false;
        else return true;            

    }
```